# Make object orbit around another with Degrees only (Not radians)

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I'm currently developing something that requires objects to orbit around another. Though, I am limited. I cannot use Radians to achieve this. I have access to sin and cos, and the degrees. But I cannot use radians (it breaks everything). Note that this is within Minecraft and the values there cannot hold floats or doubles. So, an answer like `0.017` will be `17`. For this reason, I cannot use radians.

The function to calculate sin and cos is limited between -180 to 180. This means I cannot simply turn `0.787` radians into `787` radians, as that's out of the limit, and the answer returned would be completely wrong.

Right now the code would be something like this:

```
var distance = 100; // from the centre of orbit
var degrees = 45; // around a 360 degree orbit
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

var x = Math.cos(radians) * distance;
var y = Math.sin(radians) * distance;
```

But that code completely relies on degrees being converted into radians. I cannot do this, because of Minecraft's integer limits, and how the functions calculate sin and cos. It just is simply not possible.

So the main questions is:
How can I find future position of an object with just the degrees, sin and cos?
(Perhaps base the answer as if the degrees were 45 for instance)

Comment: Define `it` :) There's quite a lot of things working right now to get the sin and cos to actually work, haha

Comment: To what degree are floats allowed?

Comment: I mean, if floats aren't allowed at all, sin and cos would be useless since they themselves return float values only

Comment: All values are multipled by 1000 to make them integers. Floats are not allowed at all. The system only allows for integers.